# Ripples Not Drawing Correctly

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, android-recyclerview, ripple

I created two simple `Drawables` that utilize the `ripple` and are applied to a list of buttons generated by a `RecylerView`.

**Drawable One:**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ffffffff">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/doesnt_matter" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="3dp">
            <solid android:color="@color/store_closed"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**Drawable Two:**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#ffffffff">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/doesnt_matter" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="3dp">
            <solid android:color="@color/store_closed"/>
            <corners android:radius="3dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

In my adapter, I've set it up where the background of the button will be set to one of the two drawables, depending on an arbitrary boolean value.

```
if (isStoreOpen) {
    storeOpen.setBackground(bgStoreOpen);
} else {
    storeOpen.setBackground(bgStoreClosed);
}
```

Unfortunately, I get some weird behavior with the buttons. Sometimes, the ripples won't show up at all, and other times the ripple will appear on the button below it in the RecyclerView. Here's a video of what's happening (**note** I'm clicking on the bottom button): https://www.dropbox.com/s/ge5u7r7q2rfstnk/weirdRipples.mp4?dl=0

Any ideas? Thanks for your help, and let me know if you need any more of the code!

Comment: I think your top button's ripple is working fine?